# Params are doubled in rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, marionette

I am updating a model from client side with backbone and on server side I am retrieving double parameters:

```
{"_id"=>"5209df7c2e21a971fd000002",
 "name"=>"Gary Miller",
 "email"=>"gary.miller@att.net",
 "last_login"=>"2013-03-18T20:37:53+00:00",
 "timezone"=>"Central Time (US & Canada)",
 "mobile"=>nil,
 "address"=>nil,
 "address_attributes"=>{},
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"users",
 "id"=>"5209df7c2e21a971fd000002",
 "user"=>
  {"_id"=>"5209df7c2e21a971fd000002",
   "email"=>"gary.miller@att.net",
   "name"=>"Gary Miller",
   "last_login"=>"2013-03-18T20:37:53+00:00",
   "timezone"=>"Central Time (US & Canada)",
   "mobile"=>nil}}
```

On client side in the network inspector I inspected the payload and this is the data the client is sending:

```
_id: "5209df7c2e21a971fd000002"
address: null
address_attributes: {}
email: "gary.miller@att.net"
last_login: "2013-03-18T20:37:53+00:00"
mobile: null
name: "Gary Miller"
timezone: "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

The double params thing is bothering me. So any ideas to resolve is welcome.

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: The view is a backbone view and template... Si that is why I paster the network request payload instead...

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because what is on config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

More information on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is a shortcut by rails to create a hash with attributes that exist in the model after looking through the params hash. You might think that there is duplicate data being sent but it is just the original set of data grouped in a convenient way.

For example to create a new user with mass assignment, you can do :

```
new_user = User.new(params[:user])
```

new_user will now have all the attributes set from the hash user.